# Recursive algorithm for a very specific application (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

For expository purposes let *t* = 7 and consider the list *L* = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]. Note that the product of all elements of *L* is 1 mod *t*. Note that if we replace any pair of entries in *L* with their product mod *t*, e.g. [3*3, 3, 3, 3, 3] = [2, 3, 3, 3, 3] mod *t* we obtain another list with unital product. What I would like is to determine the set of complete distinct lists obtained from *L* in this way. Writing out the collection manually (I believe this is everything for the list *L*):

```
[2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[6, 3, 3, 3]
[2, 2, 3, 3]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 6, 3]
[4, 3, 3]
[4, 2]
[5, 3]
```

Looking for an elegant python solution that I can apply to any *t* and any such list with elements having a unit product.

What I've tried: I suspect that this could be an application of a graph walking algorithm, and have essentially written out the (likely complete) lists above manually walking over some kind of binary tree where a split occurs each time a subproduct is evaluated and included in the list. Unsure about how to effectively/exhaustively walk this hypothetical tree.

This is not part of a homework problem, just came up against this question in other personal research.

Comment: Well stated question! What have you tried so far, and what were your results? Unfortunately this is not a code-writing service and we ask that you include a [mcve] showing your efforts and what specific issues you ran into so that we can provide specific help

Comment: The description does not imply that this is order dependent. Why does the expected output not contain permutations, e.g. ``[3, 5]``? Is this implied by "distinct lists"?

Comment: Yes I am not concerned with the ordering, just the list of elements.

Comment: One solution is to look at the integer partitions of the length of *L*. If ```(p_1,...,p_k)``` is such a partition then ```[3^{p_1},...,3^{p_k}]``` gives all lists I'm interested in. Thanks everyone!